# How to store a JWT refreshToken cookie response

Tags: vue.js, cookies, graphql, jwt, saleor

I'm trying to authenticate a user with JWT using GraphQL. Once I login the user I receive the token as a JSON response and a httponly cookie storing the refresh token. (Server-side is using Saleor-core)

From the documentation of Saleor and some other blog-posts I assume that this response cookie should now be stored in the browser and whenever I need to refresh a token the cookie-refreshToken is used to authenticate my request. However, when I switch tabs to "Application" in my dev tools it's just empty.

What is the normal behaviour of the browser after receiving a cookie response? Do I need some extra code to somehow "save" that response cookie?

Did not really find anyone else having this problem so I think the mistake must be somewhere else.

**UPDATE**

I read somewhere the issue might be that there is no "secure" flag, which resulted from the server debug mode. I turned it off, but the cookie is still not being set.

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 23 Sep 2021 13:32:33 GMT
Server: uvicorn
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://rewhite-86006--beta-duoa0dwg.web.app
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Authorization-Bearer
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 912
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Set-Cookie: refreshToken=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MzI0MDM5NTQsIm93bmVyIjoic2FsZW9yIiwiZXhwIjoxNjM0OTk1OTU0LCJ0b2tlbiI6Ijd2b0VmMm1DNlZZSyIsImVtYWlsIjoiSnVsaWFuLkZpbmtlQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInR5cGUiOiJyZWZyZXNoIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6IlZYTmxjam8zTmc9PSIsImlzX3N0YWZmIjpmYWxzZSwiY3NyZlRva2VuIjoiWm55ek9xVG9rOU9GYXlDZXY0cjFxMUxnaktnTXRRR0VNUVJEalR1eTJDZ1IyOW1GSVBxQ1B1T1hZcTFQNk92cyJ9.Cl6PmoLkO9Hlh36tDOuyNLQCib4FVBwn32hhnmd7Q4E; expires=Sat, 23 Oct 2021 13:32:34 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=2592000; Path=/; Secure
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Request Headers:

```
POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1
Host: rewhite-saleor-engine.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 318
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
content-type: application/json
Accept: */*
Origin: https://rewhite-86006--beta-duoa0dwg.web.app
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://rewhite-86006--beta-duoa0dwg.web.app/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Thanks for your help!

[image: Graphql cookie response]

[image: No cookies]

Comment: I notice that your Response Cookie's `Domain` attribute is different from the one you have in your Application Cookies. Might be worth navigating to the domain url provided by the cookie in your browser and check if the cookie is available there.

Comment: @Mythos thanks, this what a good hint. Unfortunately the cookie is also not available there. Maybe it was just not saved as the Domain was different?

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought, I just wanted to crosscheck in case I'm wrong. Mind if I add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Domain` attribute on you cookie seems to be different from the origin of your request. You're making a cross-site request and receiving a Set Cookie response from the server (of a different domain).

Normally we run into this issue when running backend and frontend on different domains (for e.g. `localhost:3000` and `localhost:8080`).

**Solution:**

1. Recent Chrome browser versions (from 2020) will only set cookies received from cross-site requests if cookie has `SameSite=None` and `Secure` attributes set. With `Secure` set, a cookie will only be sent to server over HTTPS protocol (you need to implement SSL).
   As of now, you don't have set either. `SameSite` defaults to `Lax` not `None`. You need to explicitly set it.

*OR*

2. You need implement a proxy such that you will request your webapp on `https://rewhite-86006--beta-duoa0dwg.web.app` and your webapp will proxy this to your Saleor engine domain `rewhite-saleor-engine.herokuapp.com`. How you do that depends on what frameworks you're using for serving your webapp. You haven't mentioned your it in your question, but I notice you've tagged it under `vue.js`, so I'll assume that you're using Vue CLI for serving a Vue app.

Its very simple to set up a proxy with Vue CLI. Just look for `vue.config.js` file in your root directory. If its not there, create it and paste the code below:

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/graphql': {
                target: 'https://rewhite-saleor-engine.herokuapp.com',
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Now instead of fetching the refreshToken from `rewhite-saleor-engine.herokuapp.com/graphql`, you should send the request to your webapp at `https://rewhite-86006--beta-duoa0dwg.web.app/graphql`, and your web app local server will forward the request to your Saleor backend on Heroku. To your browser it will appear as though the request's response came form the webapp itself, so it won't be a cross-site request anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I run couple of test now and unfortunately none worked. I now got the secure flag, SSL is implemented and I'm even running the request from mydomain.com to saleorengine.mydomain.com. However, SameSite is empty - I guess this can only be set on server side? Or is there some logic behind not setting this value from the perspective of backend developement?

Comment: There is a demo store by Saleor at https://demo.saleor.io/ and if you click on the account icon in the menu and login with the example credentials a refreshCookie is set (even though SameSite is empty,too).

Comment: Yes, typically a server sends a response with the Set-Cookie header, all the cookie options are defined in this header, and then Chrome decides to set it. You can modify these options in your browser once the cookie is set, but in your case its not getting set at all.
`demo.saleor.io` works because its not making a cross-site request. Notice the `Domain` attribute in that cookie is same as the URL.

Comment: If the server is not in your control, then I'd suggest you try my second solution. Implement a proxy in your webapp. So that from the browser's perspective, its not a cross-site request since its sent to your webapp frontend's server (`https://rewhite-86006--beta-duoa0dwg.web.app`), and Chrome will be happy to set your cookie.

Comment: I‘m running the Saleor Core on a Heroku server as it‘s open source (currently in beta). Might be a bug - but what should I look out for on server side to fix it? I think the function can be found here : saleor/core/jwt.py at „create_refresh_token“

Comment: Looked into [jwt.py](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/saleor/core/jwt.py). They have properly decoupled it from cookie stuff. Its just a module they're using for jwt related operations. But I'm not concerned, I'd suggest you to go with my 2nd solution. You haven't mentioned your frontend framework in question, but you've tagged it `vue.js`, so I'll update my answer based on that assumption.

Comment: @Julian Check my updated answer

Comment: Did not work unfortunately. Cookie domain is still the same. (Yes, I'm using Vue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237495/discussion-between-mythos-and-julian).

Comment: Recent updates on the backend now send the cookie-response Secure, HttpOnly and SameSite : None - however the cookie is still not saved. What might be the issue now? 

Your answer regarding proxy worked well for development (and still is) but for production it basically should work with it.

Comment: What's the difference between your development and production environment? Where is the backend server and frontend server hosted? The proxy method should work for production as well, in fact that's how it is commercially done.

Comment: Backend at Heroku, Frontend at Google Firebase. The proxy is defined in the vue.config via "devServer: {}" - but theres no documentation about proxy in production.

Comment: Then you need to look into how you can proxy requests with Firebase hosting. So firebase will send all "/graphql" requests to your heroku backend.